# Can't watch 4OD (UK)

Tags: flash, streaming

When I try to watch streaming video from 4OD, I get a message saying I have to update Flash. After going through the update process, I get a message saying my flash is already up to date. 
I used to be able to watch it without problem.

I can still watch all the other streaming sites I generally watch: Youtube, BBC iplayer, OCS. 
What is hapenning and what are the possible solutions.

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: What if you click the "Check Now" button on [this page](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html)?

Comment: Hello, I'm using Firefox, but I also tried Chromium, with exactly the same outcome.

Comment: Hello, I'm using Firefox, but I also tried Chromium, with exactly the same outcome. When I tried the "check now" button on the page Gunnar mentioned, it goes through all the same process as before - donload Flash, install, then the notice "flash already installed".

Comment: I'm in UK and use this setup:- If you get yourself a Chromecast (around £20) & connect to TV this works with Ubuntu 18.04 with Chromium Web Browser providing you connect Chromium to Chromecast before starting a programme. Not ideal, but 4OD has lots of good stuff, particularily Walter Presents World Drama which I've spent a year watching so far.